# Order by highest hasmany

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables Parts has many Offers.

I need to get all Parts sorted by Offers highest price or quantity, where offers price > 0 and offers quantity > 0.

Price and quantity are calculated fields.

How to achieve this?

I tried

```
Part::
addSelect([
  'quantity' => Offer::select('quantity')
    ->orderBy('quantity', 'desc')
    ->whereColumn('part_id', 'parts.id')
    ->limit(1)
])
->orderBy('quantity', 'desc')
->paginate(3)
```

But this way i cannot filter parts by quantity > 0 and price > 0

Also since quantity is calculated field when i do this

```
->addSelect([
    'qty' => Offer::select(['quantity * 2 as qty'])
        ->orderBy('qty', 'asc')
        ->whereColumn('part_id', 'parts.id')
        ->limit(1)
])
```

I get Reference 'qty' not supported error

More explanation:

Each Part has many Offers. 
Each Offer has many Shippings. 
Offer`s

```
available_quantity = quantity - sum of shipped quantities
```

I need to show Parts where available_quantity > 0 and sort Parts by available_quantity

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Alen question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order it like this:

```php
$shipping = Shipping::groupBy('offer_id')->select(DB::raw('SUM(quantity) AS sum_quantity'), 'offer_id', 'id');

Part::join('offers', 'offers.part_id', '=', 'parts.id')
    ->join(DB::raw("({$shipping->toSql()}) AS ship"), 'ship.offer_id', '=', 'offers.id')
    ->select('parts.*',DB::raw('MAX(offers.quantity - ship.sum_quantity) AS avaliable_quantity'))
    ->groupBy('part.id')
    ->orderBy('avaliable_quantity', 'desc')
    ->paginate(3)
```

Comment: i mean sometimes i need to sort by quantity and sometimes by price and this values calculated using fields from other joined tables

Comment: @user1192474 I can't get that. what is sort by quantity and sometimes by price?

Comment: Let me explain. each Part has many Offers. Each Offer has many Shippings. Offer available_quantity = quantity - sum of shipped quantities. I need to show Parts where available_quantity > 0 and sort Parts by available_quantity

Comment: @user1192474 `quantity - sum of shipped quantities`, is quantity is the column of offers?

Comment: yes, but i need to show parts with available quantity which counts like "quantity - sum of quantities shipped"

Comment: @user1192474 this `avaliable_quantity` is belongs to parts, not offers?

Comment: Part has many Offer. Offer has many Shipping. Offer and Shipping have field quantity. Offer calculated available_quantity = Offer quantity minus sum of related Shipping quantity. I need to sort Parts by Offer calculated available_quantity

Comment: @user1192474 how do u sort parts by offers, if parts has many offers with diff avaliable_quantity? Do u mean sorts  offers or sort parts

Comment: I get all parts. For each part i need to find offer with highest available quantity which is calculated from offer quantity minus sum of shippings quantity for this offer. Next i need to order parts using this calculated value. And finally i need to leave only parts with highest offer available quantity > 0

Comment: Its ok if i change join shipping to leftJoin and added having available_quantity > 0, but what if offers table has price column and i need to get price that correspond with this max available_quantity offer?

Comment: may be i need to create another question for this and describe all my tables...

Comment: @user1192474 yes, this will a little complicated, I think you need to create another question.